# llenar tabla de manera vertical para mostrar equivalencias entre marcas e imprir en pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf

tengo el siguiente codigo  y me muestra esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito que me llene la tabla de manera vertical  de la siguiente manera
este es un ejemplo de como se debería llenar  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código que tengo hasta ahora

```html
       <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="titulo" colspan="6"><h3>Equivalencias </h3></th>
                    <th class="fecha" width="20Px" colspan="4"><img src="<?php echo $base64; ?>"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="fecha" colspan="10"><?php echo "$fechaActual";?></th> </tr>
                <tr>
                </thead>
                <?php 
        foreach($marca as $mar){
    ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="marca"  colspan="2"><?php echo $mar['marca']; ?></th>
                  
                    <th class="marca" colspan="2" ><?php echo $mar['marca']; ?></th>
                 
                    <th class="marca" colspan="2"><?php echo $mar['marca']; ?></th>
                 
                    <th class="marca" colspan="2"><?php echo $mar['marca']; ?></th>
                    
                    <th class="marca" colspan="2"><?php echo $mar['marca']; ?></th>

               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><h6>Codigo Marca</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>Codigo WEB</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>Codigo Marca</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>Codigo WEB</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>Codigo Marca</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>Codigo WEB</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>Codigo Marca</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>Codigo WEB</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>Codigo Marca</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>Codigo WEB</h6></th>
                   
                </tr>
            </thead>
         <tbody>
                <?php $j = 0; ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php 
                        foreach($equivalencias as $equivalencia){ 
                            if($j == 5){ 
                                $j = 0;
                                ?>
                                    </tr><tr>
                                <?php 
                            }
                            if($equivalencia['id_marca'] == $mar['id']){
                        ?>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $equivalencia['codigo_marca']; ?>
                                </td>
                                
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $equivalencia['codigo']; ?>
                                </td>

                            <?php 
                                $j++; 
                            }
                        } 
                        if( $j != 0){
                            for($i = 0; $i < 5 - $j; $i++){
                                ?>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php 
        }
            ?>
        </table>
```

Esta tabla muestra equivalencia de una nuestra marca (marca web) con otras marcas, esto esta cargada  en base de dato. tengo una tabla equivalencia marca donde guardo el nombre de la marca y  otra tabla llamada equivalencia donde tengo la relacion de cada código de marca con el código de la marca web. espero me puedan ayudar con esta inconveniente. estoy usando tablas por que los flex y grid de css no me funcionan al imprimir en pdf